# Read specific information from an .xlsx file using java

Tags: java, arrays, string, datetime, type-conversion

The xlsx file has contents in the below format [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4exlw.png)

I want to capture the information highlighted into different fields that go into the database as a string

Final date would be in the 3rd row highlighted and that would be stored in string finaldate;

Row no :6 that has final status as Fail would go into string Status;

And then,Row 24:DATAID the value before . has to be retrieved like 3ABC36812 has to be stored using string.split(".")[0] into string dataid;

Since these columns might be varying in different rows within the excel sheet,how do i capture these values specifically and accurately using BufferedReader component

```
 String line;
      try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(str)))
       {
          for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
              br.readLine();
          line = br.readLine();
          System.out.println(line);
           
if (line.startsWith("FINAL DATE:"))
{
string [] split=line.split(":").[1]
//not sure coz even HH:MM has the colon in it,so how to extract the date value alone
finaldate=split; ///????
}

//so i am checking if the column dataid exists using starts with and then fetch the row below that having the dataid into string data column
if (line.startsWith("DATAID"))
{
needcat=true;
System.out.println( "bye "+needcat);
}
```

I dont want to use the apache poi since my version of java does not support that and i would prefer to explore using the bufferedreader/filestream components in java

Comment: The xlsx format is non-trivial. Do you even know the format? And how can your version of Java not support a library that's been out for a decade or two?

Comment: Have you been able to locate even one fleid in this file?? Thats your starting point

Comment: I can read some ,but not all the fields,is there a best way to read them one by one?

Comment: @joseph larson xlsx format is important coz when i try to read the file it shows all invalid characters using buffered reader and only supports csv fromat.Not sure how to accomodate xlsx file format and read specific lines to retrieve the values!

Comment: Could you, no, could your IDE please indent your code properly so we can read it without too much strain? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't think you're going to get what you want the way you're trying to do it. Take a look at this page:

https://docs.fileformat.com/spreadsheet/xlsx/

It looks like they're suggesting that .xlsx files are zip files.

If that's true, you're not going to have success the way you're reading it.

I don't understand why you can't use POI. If you need Java prior to 11, maybe you can grab an older copy from 10 years ago or something.

Otherwise, you'll want to use a Zip library to unpack it first.

Comment: Thanks Joseph for the analysis,i understand POI is the way to go forward but i was wondering if i can do it using buffered reader module library and i was able to do it for csv and text files with ease but not for the xlsx files coz the delimiter is totally different and i get special characters when i use br.readLine() into the file.

Comment: James, according to the page I linked, xlsx files are ZIP files. It's not a simple text file. It's not going to be parseable in a simple fashion like you're trying.